# 100% accuracy during validation

Tags: google-earth-engine

I learned about supervised classification using random forest algorithm.

Details:

1. Classifier: `smileRandomForest` with `10` decision trees.
2. Classes: forest, vegetation non-forest, non-vegetated area, and water.
3. Class Properties:  `name` and id`.`
4. Sampling: `sampleRegions` with `500` limit for each class and also, I used `rancomCloumn` function for each class sample.

Then, I divided my total samples into two classes:

1. For classification (70% from total samples)
2. Second, for validation (30% from total samples)

Then, I got my classification result.
After that, I tried to validate it with validation samples (30%) 
and I got 100% accuracy.

Is that normal? Or perhaps I made some mistakes in my code.

This my GEE code: https://code.earthengine.google.com/82769aa8927ccc5262eedfa24c657799

Answer (score 3):

I'm not an expert, and cannot tell if it's a normal accuracy or not. But I do spot a mistake, causing your training data to include all your test data:

```
var training = total_samples.limit(1231, 'lc')//70% from total samples
var test = total_samples.limit(527, 'lc')//30% from total samples
```

This sorts your collection by `lc`, your random column, and then take the first 70% for training data, and the first 30% for test data. What you want here is the last 30%. You could do like this instead:

```
var training = total_samples.filterMetadata('lc', 'less_than', 0.7)
var test = total_samples.filterMetadata('lc', 'greater_than', 0.7)
```

This should give you about 70/30 distribution between training and test data.

Answer (score 0):

I think that @Daniel Wiell correctly spotted the mistake in your code.

Random forest classifier is calibrated on the training samples, therefore it will fit very well to the training samples (especially if you have a large number of variables as input). As you reuse part of the training sample for your "validation", what you measure is the "Out Of Box" quality of your model. This shows that the model was able to use its variable to discriminate your 4 land cover classes (which is good, 100 % is possible but rarely achieved), but does not tell how well your model will generalize (if you have much more dimensions than samples, you model could be overfitted and this kind of model have poor generalization properties (that this, they fail to work well with other datasets). So it has to be tested with **independant** validation sample in order to achieve a rigourous quality assessment.